# Object of a subclass in a variable of type interface (implemente by superclass) calls superclass method?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an interface, a superclass that implements it, and a subclass that extends the superclass. Then I have test that creates an object of the type of the subclass, but stores it in a variable of the type of the interface. When I use a method that is defined in the interface, implemented in the superclass, and overridden in the subclass, it calls the method from the superclass. Why is this? I can't change the test class, but did I do something wrong with the subclass?

```
public interface SampleInterface<T extends Comparable<T>>{
    void add(T element);
//other methods, etc
}


public class SampleClassA<T extends Comparable<T>> implements SampleInterface<T> {
    public void add(){
        System.out.println("super");
    }
}

@Override
public class SampleClassB<T extends Comparable<T>> extends SampleClassA<T> {
    public void add(){
        System.out.println("sub");
    }
}
```

Then I want to use the code in a test that looks like this:

```
private SampleInterface<Integer> test = new SampleClassB<Integer>();
test.add();
```

And it prints "super", but I want "sub". This is a simplified version of my code, also.

Comment: Showing the actual code and result might help us understand your problem better.

Comment: Most probably you did not use "@Override" which means you did not override but hide the method. But without code, this is just a wild guess.

Comment: even without @Override, given the method has the correct signature, it would work and the method of the subclass be called.... but yes code is required to see what the problem is

Comment: @Fildor all adding the Override does, is adding a compile time check that 'll verify that there is a superclass/interface that contains this method to be overridden. It doesn't change the behaviour of the code.

Comment: @Stultuske you are right. Please ignore that part of my comment.

Comment: After code added: How can this compile? Is this the complete code?

Comment: In the code you posted the interface's `add` method has a different signature than the `add` methods of the classes.

Comment: Are you sure that nothing assigns test a different value? E.g. you can find reassignments by making the field final and recompiling; a reassignment would be a compilation error.

Comment: This code compiles- this is not the complete code, but all the relevant info. Nothing changes test. I am not allowed to change the interface and removing "public" from the method header of either class results in an error- I cannot reduce the visibility from the interface.

Comment: I just typed the code above just out of curiosity and it works like it should. It prints 'sub'. The problem is elsewhere. My guess is you oversimplified when posting and in reality the SampleClassB method doesn't have the same signature as the SampleClassA add method.

Comment: @MikeKeegan the code given in this question cannot compile, for the reason Eran says. You would get an error like "SampleClassA is not abstract but does not implement add(T)". Also: Override should go on methods be overridden, not classes (I'd be surprised if that compiled too).

Comment: OK I'm really dumb and there's another error that makes it look a lot like this is happening, when in actuality it isn't. Thanks guys for helping but my problems lie elsewhere. At least I'm not going insane.